# jQuery Mobile: page transitions cannot be set to none on Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, dialog, transition

Well, not in my case anyway.

Since page transitions as developed by jQueryMobile are very shaky when used on specific Android devices, I wanted to turn them off.

So I have set the data-transition attribute on every link and button to 'none'.

Also I am both using the setting $.mobile.defaultDialogTransitions = 'none' AND setting data-transition='none' on every link to a dialog. The default setting may not be coming through because the mobileinit event (in which you are supposed to set the defaults) is not firing.

And yet when I launch on my Android, all dialogs do a popup/popdown transition on open/close, and moving to any regular page transitions with a slide.

What's going on?

Comment: are transitions showing when you use another user agent?  What do you get if you use a desktop browser?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how well-mannered it is to answer my own question. But thanks in part to Dan I figured it out.

The mobileinit event didn't fire because I wasn't binding it precisely as specified (that is: after the jquery script, but before the jquery mobile script).

When I got it to fire, the transitions behaved just as I desired.

I haven't figured out why the data-transition attributes weren't doing their job when the default wasn't working. But that's theory.

And of course, once it worked on one browser, it worked everywhere.